# Assert.equal is not available when running Truffle Tests

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a simple contract and I am trying to write Solidity tests for that contract in Truffle. Below are the code samples -

```
File: dummycontract.sol

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract DummyContract {

    uint[] public elements;

    function addElement(uint element) public {
        elements.push(element);
    }

    function getNumberOfElements() public view returns(uint) {
        uint numElements = uint(elements.length);
        return numElements;
    }

}
```

And the test file -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/dummycontract.sol";

contract TestZombieFactory {

    function testInitialState() public {
        DummyContract dummyContract = DummyContract(DeployedAddresses.DummyContract());
        uint numberOfElements = dummyContract.getNumberOfElements();
        Assert.equal(numberOfElements == 0);
    }

}
```

On running `truffle test`, I get the following error -

```
TypeError: Member "equal" is not available in type(library Assert) outside of storage.
        Assert.equal(numberOfElements == 0);
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `Assert.equal()` is not correct. It expects two values and does the comparison within the function. The function signature is

```
function equal(uint A, uint B, string message) constant returns (bool result)
```

Change your test contract to the following and it will work.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/dummycontract.sol";

contract TestZombieFactory {
    function testInitialState() public {
        DummyContract dummyContract = DummyContract(DeployedAddresses.DummyContract());
        uint numberOfElements = dummyContract.getNumberOfElements();
        Assert.equal(numberOfElements, 0, "Number of elements should be 0");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should replace

```
Assert.equal(numberOfElements == 0);
```

with

```
Assert.equal(numberOfElements,0);
```